# How to draw animated chart in android

Tags: android, animation, charts

Actually, I have drawn pie chart and line chart. I want to make it animated. Animated means, it does not come from left or right or top or bottom, but line chart should draw with animation.

Ex : each point should draw one by one. I tried with thread but i m failed. Is it possible with handler?

I tried in oDraw(Canvas canvas) method. I tried to put thread with sleep time. Let me know any more ideas.

Give me some idea. Thanks.